# Reversing an ObservableCollection<objectType> using linq

Tags: c#, linq, windows-phone-7, observablecollection, reverse

This one should be easy, and im ashamed i havent figured it out myself yet.
I'm trying to reverse the order of a list of items in my wp7 app. The list is an ObservableCollection. 
When using system.linq, intellisense lets me do this: myList.Reverse();  ,but this doesnt seem to work. Am i doing something wrong, or is there some other way i can do this easily?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Doesn't seem to work", how? Do you mean the UI doesn't show the items in reversed order?

Comment: Related question, but not necessarily a duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10413535/reverse-order-of-observablecollection

Answer (score 34, accepted):

[Reverse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358497.aspx) returns an IEnumerable, it does not modify the collection. To modify the collection you could do

```
collection = new ObservableCollection<YourType>(collection.Reverse());
```

Comment: Thats the kind of solution i was looking for. And it worked like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: How can this work, when collection is an ObservableCollection? That class has no Reverse...? At least, that's the message I get when I try this.

Comment: Reverse is an extension method within the System.Linq.Enumerable class. Add the using statement for System.Linq;

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to recreate the collection:

```
for (int i = 0; i < collection.Count; i++)
  collection.Move(collection.Count - 1, i);
```

Answer (score 0):

make a class that inherits the observablecollection(of T) and implement a sort object in it.  This is a vb.net brute force way of doing that:

```
    Public Sub Sort(ByVal comparer As IComparer(Of T))
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim index As T
    For i As Integer = 1 To Count - 1
        index = Me(i)
        j = i
        While (j > 0) AndAlso (comparer.Compare(Me(j - 1), index) = 1)
            Me(j) = Me(j - 1)
            j = j - 1
        End While
        Me(j) = index
    Next
End Sub
```