# C# - WPF Reverse binded ObservableCollection in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, combobox, observablecollection, reverse

I have a ObservableCollection which is binded as ItemSource to my ComboBox. It's a ComboBox which shows you your changes which you've done. My Problem is now, that the newest Change is displayed on the bottom of the list.
I tried to reverse it in the property, but when I return `ComboboxName.Reverse()` I get an **IEnumerable** back. I also don't want to make a 2nd collection with the reversed data.

An other way would be to solve this in XAML. Does someone have an idea how I can do that?

I found this answer here, but i dont get it how i can implement it.
[Reverse order of ObservableCollection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10413535/reverse-order-of-observablecollection)

Comment: What is the problem with the linked answer? What is not working?

Comment: When i put my ObservableCollection binding instead of `{Binding Path=DocProps}`, then nothing apears in the ComboBox. I also don't now for what this `scm:` stands for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

scm stands for

```
xmlns:scm="clr-namespace:System.ComponentModel;assembly=WindowsBase"
```

There a solution that works for me. You have to adapt it to your case:

```
<Window.Resources>
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="customerGroups" Source="{Binding Path=Customers}">
        <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
            <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="IsCompany"></PropertyGroupDescription>
        </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
        <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
            <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="IsCompany" Direction="Descending"/>
            <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="DisplayName" Direction="Ascending"/>
        </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
    </CollectionViewSource>
</Window.Resources>
```

Then you reference this resource as ItemsSource of your ComboBox, and bind the content to the property you need:

```
 <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource customerGroups}}">
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path= FirstName}"></TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox>
```